# Log4Net out of a IIS Hosted WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, log4net

Good day folks

I must have read about 20 different articles/approaches about how to implement log4net in ASP.NET 1.0 / 2.0 and various other application types.

[Link #1](https://www.bryancook.net/2008/05/log4net-configuration-made-simple.html)

[Link #2](https://web.archive.org/web/20160928002238/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/bsherwin/archive/2008/02/15/119657.aspx)

[Link #3](https://haacked.com/archive/2006/07/09/ConfiguringLog4NetWithASP.NET2.0InMediumTrust.aspx/)

Well, above articles are all ok, i did try/follow all of them, but i never got a log file..

What i have:
IIS Hosted WCF Service.

What i want:

Logging using log4net - well, first i wanted to use Tracing (like Trace.Write in System.Diagnostics) then the Microsoft Enterprise Library and finally i'm stuck trying to figure out how to setup/configure log4net for my logging needs.

My question:

How to get log4net writing a logfile? i mean:

- is it a security problem? do i really need to procmon this?
- is the problem to write to a log file (security)?
- is the problem that the configuration file cannot be read?

i tried:

- Specifying the log4net.config using

  [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFileExtension = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
- Specifying the configuration in web.config after the  block. When i did that i wasn't able to run the Web Application anymore (IIS reports corrupt web.config).

Help in this issue is really appreciated!

Christian

Comment: Update: it seems (procmon pointed me in this direction) that w3wp.exe is looking in %Windir%\SysWOW64\inetsrv for the log4net.config file!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my fault. It was the declaration when ConfigFileExtension is declared, log4net searches for .dll. in the web root. Just changed that to ConfigFile and it's working like a charm. my careless mistake...!

Christian